# Oracle express edition 10g trigger problem at runtime

Tags: plsql, database-trigger, dml, oracle-xe

Below image is showing error.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yuvan.png)

I have created this simple trigger in plsql.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR6
 BEFORE UPDATE ON EMPLOYEE
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO PRAC14 (EMP_NO,EMP_NAME,EMP_SAL,DEPT_NO)
 VALUES(:OLD.EMP_NO,:OLD.EMP_NAME,:OLD.EMP_SAL,:OLD.DEPT_NO); 
 END;
 /
```

after running above code it shows TRIGGER CREATED.
Then when I am updating my employee table like

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE
SET EMP_SAL=3000
WHERE DEPT_NO=10
```

I am getting this error message

> ORA-04098: trigger 'Username.TR' is invalid and failed re-validation.I am using Oracle  database 10g express edition.

Comment: Trigger is created but it is in INVALID state, so it cannot be executed. You must revise and correct it. There must be some kind of error in the code (sorry, I don't have any Oracle for validate your code).

Comment: Your 2nd commend is wrong, @David. What would `:new.old.emp_no` be?

Comment: I have mentioned :OLD.attribute_name pseudo record name then why I have to include :new.OLD.attribute_name??

Comment: Totally correct Littlefoot. Thanks.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the difference:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR6
                          ---
```

vs.

```
ORA-04098: trigger 'Username.TR' is invalid 
                             --
```

It seems that there's yet another trigger on that table which is invalid. Either fix it, or drop it.

---

Check triggers by running

```
select table_name, trigger_name, trigger_type from user_triggers order by 1, 2;
```

---

**[Example]**

It is based on Scott's EMP table. Trigger intentionally uses `:old.empnox`, a column which doesn't exist. It leads to error you got:

```
SQL> create table prac14  as select empno, ename, sal, deptno
  2  from emp where 1 = 2;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace trigger tr6
  2    before update on emp
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    insert into prac14 (empno,ename,sal,deptno)
  6    values(:old.empnox,:old.ename,:old.sal,:old.deptno);
  7  end;
  8  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL>
SQL> update emp set sal = 3000 where deptno = 10;
update emp set sal = 3000 where deptno = 10
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04098: trigger 'SCOTT.TR6' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

But, if trigger code is fixed, everything runs OK:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger tr6
  2    before update on emp
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    insert into prac14 (empno,ename,sal,deptno)
  6    values(:old.empno,:old.ename,:old.sal,:old.deptno);
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
SQL> update emp set sal = 3000 where deptno = 10;

3 rows updated.

SQL>
```

I suggest you post the same, executed in your database.

Comment: No I have checked with (TR1,TR2,TR3,TR4,TR5,TR6) all six trigger names, then also it is showing me same erroe 'Username.TR' is in valid.

Comment: I edited my message and added query which will show all triggers you have. Check the relevant one(s).

Comment: I fired above query got below output.

Comment: TABLE_NAME    TRIGGER_NAME    TRIGGER_TYPE

Comment: Don't post it as a comment; edit the question (original message you posted).

Comment: I got entries from TR0 to TR6.All having table name EMPLOYEE and BEFORE EACH ROW TRIGGER_TYPE.

Comment: Then you're misinterpreting reality. There's no trigger named **TR**, as suggested by error message you posted. Please, execute everything in SQL*Plus and copy/paste the outcome so that we could see what **exactly** you did and how Oracle responded - just like I did. See my edited answer.

Comment: No, it is not. But - I see you solved the problem; I'm glad you did.

Answer (score 0):

I have created multiple trigger for DML operation on a single table. That is why I am getting error. I have dropped all other triggers on EMPLOYEE table except TR6 and it worked.

Kudos to you @Littlefoot.